# If A is a countable set, and B is an uncountable set, then why A intersect B is a countable set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

If A is a countable set, and B is an uncountable set, then why A intersect B is a countable set?
this is what book said.
The whole text is in the picture.
I wrote my question in the picture. plz help me in this easy question.
thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZkRm.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKBIO.jpg)

Comment: $A\cap B\subset A$. What do you know about subsets of countable sets?

Comment: Keep in mind, a countable set can be a finite set.

Comment: This is not true in general: $\Bbb N \cap (-\infty, 0] = \{0\}$ which is not countable. It becomes true if you use the term "at most countable".

Comment: Count the elements of $A$. Skip the elements not in $B$.

Comment: @AlexM.: That depends on your definition of "countable". You obviously use the definition "$A$ is countable if $|A|=\aleph_0$". There's also the definition ["$A$ is countable if $|A|\le\aleph_0$".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) With that definition, the statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** All elements of $A\cap B$ are elements of $A$ **and** $B$. Therefore, one has $A \cap B \subset A$. Show that **a subset of countable set is itself a countable set**.